# Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server :1.2.0 - How to add "nonce" claim to Id Token?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-boot-3

> The nonce value is passed as part of the authorization request, and
> the authorization server must return it in the ID token. (Prevent Replay Attacks)

This is what I understood during my research and Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server :1.2.0 does not provide a build-in functionality having the nonce as a claim in Id Token.

I have been trying to add nonce to my Id Token and I am not able to get it right. I am using

**spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server version 1.2.0** with
**Spring boot 3.2.0**

```
  @Bean
  public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
    return context -> {
         if (OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType().getValue())) {
           // Customize the Claims to add custom information.
           // Add Nonce Here
         }
         if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
           // Customize the Claims to add custom information.
         }
     }
  }
```

I have tried different methods to get the nonce value from the request (HttpServletRequest),
but the only request that is coming into the `tokenCustomizer` is `http://<auth-server>/oauth2/token`.

I know that the nonce is part of authorization request ( `http://<auth-server>/oauth2/authorize` ).

How can I retrieve the `nonce` parameter from the authorization request and provide back as a claim in Id Token? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks